# UIActivityIndicatorView in a UITableViewController

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uiactivityindicatorview

I am currently updating one of my apps.  It fetches information from the internet and uses networkActivityIndicatorVisible to show and hide the Activity Indicator in the status bar.  The one complaint we have received about this, is that it is too small, and users don't know that their device is getting information.  So my idea was to utilize the spinning activity wheel in the middle of my view.  If you try to drag one out of the items, it places it in a cell, or in the header UIView that I made.  This is not what I wanted so I made it programmatically.

In the header file.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIActivityIndicatorView *mySpinner;
```

In the implementation file.

```
_mySpinner = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
_mySpinner.color = [UIColor blackColor];
_mySpinner.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = NO;
_mySpinner.hidesWhenStopped = YES;
```

I then added the spinning wheel to my view by doing the following.  Along with making my constraints.

```
[self.view addSubview:_mySpinner];

[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mySpinner
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterX
                                                     multiplier:1
                                                       constant:0]];
[self.view addConstraint:[NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_mySpinner
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                      relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                                                         toItem:self.view
                                                      attribute:NSLayoutAttributeCenterY
                                                     multiplier:0.75
                                                       constant:0]];
[_mySpinner startAnimating];
```

I ran the code and it worked fine.  Even when I rotated the spinner was where I wanted it.  However, and this is where the problem lies, when I scroll the table view, the spinner goes right along with it!

I know this is due to the fact that I added the spinner to self.view and made all the constraints with self.view.  And in the case of the UITableViewController, the table view is self.view.

The App has several tableviews and they are all quite long, many with custom cells.  I don't really want to redesign everything, but does anyone know if there is a superview to the UITableViewController that I could put my constraints onto?  I have tried a couple of things but nothing is working.  Sorry for such a long question but I was hoping someone could help out.  Thanks for reading!

Comment: Do you want to be able to interact with the rest of the table view when the spinner is presented?

Comment: @AdamPro13, not really necessary to be able to interact since the table view is pretty much empty until the data loads and the table view fills.

Comment: Then disable scrolling/user interaction when the activity indicator appears.

Comment: @AdamPro13, sorry about that, it is empty on the first go, but when you return later, sometimes the table is full.  So disabling the scrolling would not work Lyndsey Scott, thanks for the input!!

Comment: Just to clarify, I mean why not disable the scrolling/user interaction *only* when the activity indicator is visible, then enable everything if it's not.

Comment: @LyndseyScott, I see where you are going.  However, if the user is at the end of the tableview and reloading takes place, the spinner is still way up at the top.

Comment: Gotcha. Honestly I'd just recommend restructuring your view and instead make a uitableview within a uiview instead of using a uitableviewcontroller to allow for full customization. It shouldn't be that extreme of a change...

Comment: UUUGGGHHH.  To many tableviews to redesign, I was hoping no one would have mentioned that idea!!

Comment: Haha well... That's definitely the idea that makes the most sense. Sorry! ;)

Comment: That's why I never actually use `UITableViewController`, I just use a normal `UIViewController` and put a `UITableView` inside it. Way more flexible down the road if a requirement changes.

Comment: @AdamPro13, yeah down the road, I first made this project three years ago when I first started.  It has grown over the years.  And now I see your point!

Comment: This may not work the way you want it to but you could add the activity indicator directly to the `UIWindow` instead of the table view. I don't think you can interact with the view controller behind it if you do that though.

Comment: @AdamPro13, UIWindow was the way to go. Also, I can still scroll while the spinner is animating so I can interact.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

solution is just access the window of your application then attach the activity indicator for it like

```
 UIWindow *frontWindow = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] keyWindow];
    self.activity.center=frontWindow.center;

    [frontWindow addSubview:self.activity];
    [self.activity startAnimating];
```

link to code https://github.com/murali9/ActvityonTableview